# ruby and rspec - Failing test

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I am supposed to make this test pass.

```
describe 'new' do
    it "takes a parameter and returns a HangpersonGame object" do      
      @hangpersonGame = HangpersonGame.new('glorp')
      expect(@hangpersonGame).to be_an_instance_of(HangpersonGame)
      expect(@hangpersonGame.word).to eq('glorp')
      expect(@hangpersonGame.guesses).to eq('')
      expect(@hangpersonGame.wrong_guesses).to eq('')
    end
  end
```

My code is this,

```
class HangpersonGame


    attr_accessor :word
    attr_accessor :guesses
    attr_accessor :wrong_guesses

  def initialize(word)
    @word = word
    @guesses = nil
    @wrong_guesses = nil

  end
end
```

The test is failing. Why? I have run the code seperately and it seems to work.

Comment: The test expect guesses and wrong_guesses to be an empty string and not nil

Comment: Thanks, that worked.